# Create xml headers in PreferenceFragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have an application with Navigation drawer menu. I would like to show a settings fragment when i click on an item in my menu.

When i click on the item, it calls :

```
Fragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

The SettingsFragment is called :

```
import java.util.List;

import com.rss.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity.Header;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;


public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preferences, target);
    }

}
```

The problem is that i have this error :

```
The method loadHeadersFromResource(int, List<PreferenceActivity.Header>) is undefined for the type SettingsFragment
```

It seems that i can't use loadHeaderFromResources with PreferenceFragment and i must instead PreferenceActivity ?

Here is the code also of my preferences.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <header android:fragment="com.rss.preferences.ExperienceUtilisateur"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_users"
            android:title="User experience"
            android:summary="Manage notifications" >
        <extra android:name="someKey" android:value="someOtherHeaderValue" />
    </header>

    <header android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_star_10"
            android:title="Follow us"
            android:summary="Help us">
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://market.android.com/details?id=com.app.mobideals" />
    </header>

</preference-headers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Headers are only used with PreferenceActivity not PreferenceFragment